# Redesigning a function so it doesn't have global variabels in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to redesign a simple function in my program to get rid of global variables and i'm not sure what the best/most simple way is to do that.

circlefunctions.c

```
#include "circlefunctions.h"
#define PI 3.14

float   diameter;
double  radius;
double  surface;
double  outline;

void circle_functions()
{
    radius   = diameter / 2;
    surface  = PI * (radius * radius);
    outline  = 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

circlefunctions.h

```
extern float  diameter;
extern double radius;
extern double surface;
extern double outline;

void circle_functions();
```

The thing is that i currently use those variables in other parts in the program.
My solution was/is to pass the values to an array and move that data around within the program.

And someone else suggested to redesign my function to something like this:

```
double circle_functions(double diameter)
{
  double radius = diameter / 2;
  double surface = PI * (radius * radius);
  double outline = 2 * PI * radius;
  return outline;
}
```

But when i do that i get a compile error that the variable: surface is unused.
( and to be fair i'm not sure how to properly use that 2nd solution.

Hopefully someone can give me a pointer in the right direction on how to tackle this problem.

**edit**

as requested:

for example i also have a file called circlemenu.c (probably should rename that to circleresults.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "circlefunctions.h"
#include "circlemenu.h"

void info_top()
{
    system("cls");
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
    printf(" Typ the diameter of the circle: ");
}

void info_bottom()
{
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
    printf(" The radius = %f \n\n" , radius);
    printf(" The surface = %f \n\n" , surface);
    printf(" The outline = %f \n" , outline);
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: can you explain, how and where you want to use these variables in your program. As I can see, you only need any of the one variable and you can calculate rest from that. So you need to pass around only one variable

Comment: Added the info as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it like this

```
   double getRadius(double diameter)
{
  double radius = diameter / 2;
  return radius;
}

double getSurface(double diameter){
   double radius = getRadius(diameter);
   return PI * (radius * radius);
}

double getOutline(double diameter){
    double radius = getRadius(diameter);
    return 2 * PI * radius;
}
```

And you use these getter functions around your program. It will make your code readable and clean.

Use it like this:

```
void someFunction(double diameter){
    //need surface for some calculations.
    double surface = getSurface(diameter);
    //need outline to do something
    double outline = getOutline(diameter);

    //now use these as you want in your function.
}
```

As per your example:

```
void info_bottom(double diameter)
{

    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
    printf(" The radius = %f \n\n" , getRadius(diameter));
    printf(" The surface = %f \n\n" , getSurface(diameter));
    printf(" The outline = %f \n" , getOutline(diameter));
    printf(" ----------------------------------------\n");
}
```

Comment: Ahh okay i suspected that i had to do it something like that. Im verry new to programming and im trying to learn myself so its kinda hard to see what design options i should  take.

Comment: Yes, you can get the diameter from the user and then just pass it around your program. Use getter functions to fetch other information.

Comment: i certainly do. But if i have to do a special action for that on this website could you please point me to it? I was not aware i can accept answers on here.

Comment: @user2645886 on left of my answer where you see the up and down arrows, there is a "tick" sign. You have to click that to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

another popular way is to use macros.

e.g
lets say you want the surface when given a raduis.

```
 #define SURFACE(x) (PI*(x)*(x))
```

in the code you can just use it , and it doesnt matter if the radius is given as int / double / float ...
thats way this way is popular.

One caveat: macros are substituted whole wherever they are used in a program: this is potentially a huge amount of code repetition. The advantage of a macro over an actual function, however, is speed. No time is taken up in passing control to a new function, because control never leaves the home function; the macro just makes the function a bit longer.

A second caveat: function calls cannot be used as macro parameters.

(The GNU C Programming Tutorial)

Comment: Just to add, macro is replaced by the code during compile time.

Comment: Thats an interresting thing, Thank you for pointing that option out.

Comment: You should always have parentheses around macro arguments. And I would consider not recommending macros at all since the example macro evaluates its arguments twice. There is no value of using a macro instead of e.g. an inline function in this case.

Comment: @juhist thanks, i didnt noticed i forgot the perentheses.
i ment to suggest that option only as another aproach. i cant say what is the optimal way of doing somthings without looking at the broad picture.
*Apart from inlining for efficiency and conditional compilation, macros can be used to raise the abstraction level of low-level C code.*